# real user monitoring for mobile

Tags: android, ios, performance, jquery-mobile, monitoring

There are many real user monitoring ( RUM ) libraries out there for measuring browser performance for web site users like boomerang, episodes etc ..

We could use the same for mobile web, but for hybrid apps and native apps is there a similar open source library that measures key performance and speed of the app in terms of

- time to load a screen
- time to download
- time to first byte
- time to paint
- time to above the fold ..
- prefetch vc non prefetch rendering times ..
- etc ( mobile specific metrics ) ?

Also what other key metrics do you people measure for mobile apps ( both web and native app ) for real users ?

Comment: I am interested by the topic - Did you find any information about doing performance monitoring

Answer (score 1):

I believe that there are two important performance aspects for mobile web or hybrid apps

- API(also AJAX) Monitoring
- Transactions Monitoring

#### API(also AJAX) Monitoring

Mostly all mobile web apps or hybrid apps are designed with API for better performances.The performance of the app is really depends on how API works. So it is important to measure the API(AJAX) calls. Following metrics has to be measured in every AJAX call

- Response Time
- Callback Time
- Data Sent
- Data Received

#### Transactions Monitoring

All apps deal with key operations like Login, Signup Checkout, Subscribe, Buy and etc. It is valuable to measure these key transactions. These transactions involves one or more API calls. The transaction timing can be measured by noting the start time of transaction and calculating the duration at end of the transactions. This involves following metrics

- Success Response Time
- Failure Response Time

If you are looking for services with above feature, you can try out https://www.atatus.com/

PS: Web developer at Atatus.